# Unable to perform click on a custom view inflated on the top of android Canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, onclicklistener, android-custom-view, touch-event

I have been trying to build a popup on canvas click, which further has buttons on it. I inflated the popup on the canvas, but when i try clicking on it the popup closes.

This is how i am inflating the custom layout

```
 val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_marked_image_dialog, this)
            view.measure(MeasureSpec.getSize(view.measuredWidth), 
            MeasureSpec.getSize(view.measuredHeight))
            view.layout(400, 400, 400, 400)
            canvas.save()
            canvas.translate(x, y)
            view.draw(canvas)
            canvas.restore()
```

This is my custom layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/groupEditComment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_half_8">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/comment_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_standard_16"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_comment_24px" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/FS_Text_Button_Dialog_Box"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/spacing_half_8"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/button_padding_16"
            android:text="@string/edit_comment" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To enable to interact with view, you need to add `view` to parent `ViewGroup` and do not to do `view.draw(canvas)`